# How long will it take for all my badges to turn up?

Tags: discussion, badges

By current count I have 3 silver and 4 bronze badges. This is a lot less than I had before. Do they just turn up in dribs and drabs over 24-48 hours, or what?

Not that I'm driven by badges, but I'm curious to know how it works.

Comment: It might take a while since they need to be recalculated. On the other hand, you can enjoy each notification again!

Comment: Or lack thereof, if the old badge has no analogue... :-)

Comment: I feel sorry for Joel, who will have his inbox spammed with badge notifications for days...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're seeing your Meta badges. If you look from a regular MO page, you should have all your old badges.

Edit: Yep, I see 2 gold, 20 silver, and 58 bronze on your [MO user page](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4177/david-roberts). That enough for you? :)

Comment: Ah, forgot about that system. Problem solved.

Comment: I can't even accept your answer yet - need to get used to the computer nanny telling me what I can't do now. :-S